# Auto Complete is not working when i have <merge> as a child of <layout>

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete, intellisense

I have the following in my layout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:id="@+id/layoutId">

    <data>
        <variable name="data" type="com.example.android.Person"/>
    </data>

        <TextView ... //**YES** Intellisense or autocompletion

    <merge>

        <TextView ... //No Intellisense or autocompletion

        <Spinner ... //No Intellisense or autocompletion

    </merge>
</layout>
```

Any XML tag i tried to use within the `<merge>` tag doesn't popup intellisense or autocompletion.

I have tried the following;

1. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
2. File -> Power Save Mode
3. Delete .idea folder and all .iml and rebuild.

Nothing seems to work.

Intellisense/autocompletion works **outside** the  tag but not within it.

Please, does anyone have a solution?

### Temporary Fix

I changed `<merge>` to an Android `ViewGroup` (in my case `LinearLayout`) then used a `ViewStub` in my root layout.

Answer (score 1):

should be a root tag. Then completion works fine: https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Merge

Comment: I still want to maintain the `<layout>` as the root tag. So i had to do away with the `<merge>`.